# Splitting dataframe by conditions in pySpark

Tags: python, boolean, pyspark

I have a dataframe has a value of a  false, true, *or* null. I want to create two dataframes, 1) with just the True column names and 2) with just False column names. My initial thoughts are to create two dataframes (since later on they will be appended to a larger dataset) or I also thought about converting the appropriate column names to a list and then the list names to column names.

I'm new to pySpark and trying to figure how to do this without hardcoding any column names(I have a couple hundred columns)  I know that I cannot iterate through rows since it would defeat the purpose of pySpark.

Each column will only have one boolen - either a T or F, hence the multiple nulls per column.
I tried using .filter but it only filtered one column and it actually printed the all the other column as oppose to just the F columns.

```
df.filter(df.col1 == 'F').show()
```

```
df:
+----+----+----+----+-----+
|Name|col1|col2|col3|col4 |
+----+----+----+----+-----+
|   A|null|  F | T  |null |
|   A| F  |null|null|null |
|   E|null|null|null|  T  |
+----+----+----+----+-----+


EXPECTED OUTCOME

Dataframe w/ True Column Names:
+------+----+
|col3  |col4|
+------+----+

Dataframe w/ False Column Names (empty dataframe)
+------+----+
|col1  |col2|
+------+----+
```

Comment: What if col3 had both a T and and F?

Comment: @anky the original dataframe will only include one value per column. Each column will only have one boolen - either a T or F, hence the multiple nulls per column.

Comment: just to clarify, are you trying to split the main dataframe into two dataframes, where the first has columns with T and the second to have columns with F?

Comment: @Mit, yes! Exactly that. Filter the main dataframe by T/F and make those columns into their own dataframe.

Comment: and will every column always have either T or F at one row?

Comment: @Mitt, yes, every column will always have either a T or F at one of the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the `first` of each row with `ignorenulls=True` and convert to a dictionary;

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
r = df.select(*[F.first(i,ignorenulls=True).alias(i) for i in df.columns]).collect()

T = [k for k,v in r[0].asDict().items() if v=='T']
F = [k for k,v in r[0].asDict().items() if v=='F']
```

---

```
print(T)
print(F)

#['col3', 'col4']
#['col1', 'col2']
```

Comment: makes sense. however, I'm getting an empty dict. `[ ]`

Comment: `'bool' object has no attribute 'strip' ` @anky

Comment: @jessgtrz so you have boolean  `true` and not a string `T` as shown in your question? can you try `T = [k for k,v in r[0].asDict().items() if isinstance(v,bool) and v]` and 
`F = [k for k,v in r[0].asDict().items() if not v]`

Comment: sorry for not making it clear. Hmm, now I get 
`SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`@anky

Comment: @jessgtrz cant say but seems your assigning looks off. if you try my exact code it works for me with your sample data. you can lookup online for the error .

Comment: turns out, I only needed to switch my value to boolean in your suggested code.          `r = df.select(*[f.first(i,ignorenulls=True).alias(i) for i in df.columns]).collect()

standardTrue = [k for k,v in isStandardColumn[0].asDict().items() if v== 1]
standardFalse = [k for k,v in isStandardColumn[0].asDict().items() if v== 0]

print(standardTrue)
print(standardFalse) ` @anky

Comment: I have another question. thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787976/populating-column-in-dataframe-with-pyspark @anky

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

#get list of columns
dfListCols = df.columns.tolist()
#remove first column 'name'
dfListCols.pop(0)
#create lists for T/F
truesList = list()
falseList = list()
#loop over columns 
for col in dfListCols:
    #subframe with the current column
    tempDf = df[col]
    #check if contains T
    if 'T' in tempDf.values:
        #if yes add to truesList
        truesList.append(col)
    else:
        #if no add to falseList
        falseList.append(col)

#get subDFrames
trueDF = df[truesList]
falseDF = df[falseList]
```

Comment: exactly the logic I'm shooting for. Except this doesn't work in pySpark. I will try converting it to pySpark @Mit