# Populating column in dataframe with pySpark

Tags: function, dataframe, pyspark, columnsorting

new to pySpark and I'm trying to fill a column based on conditions using a list. How can I fill a column based conditions using a list?

**Python logic**

```
if  matchedPortfolios == 0:
      print("ALL")
  else:
      print(Portfolios)
```

**pySpark attempt with error**

```
#Check matching column values in order to find common portfolio names
Portfolios = set (portfolio_DomainItemLookup) & set(portfolio_dataset_standardFalse)
Portfolios #prints list of matched names OR prints  empty list

matchedPortfolios = len(Portfolios)
matchedPortfolios #prints 0 or length of list


dataset_standardFalse.withColumn('PortfolioRule', f.when( matchedPortfolios == 0, "ALL").otherwise(Portfolios)).show()
```

**TypeError: condition should be a Column**: Variable matchedPortfolios is a list. How can I fill a column based conditions using a list?

Comment: need more details, for example, what is `matchedPortfolios`?

Comment: @jxc, just added them. thanks!

Comment: are `portfolio_DomainItemLookup` and `portfolio_dataset_standardFalse` two columns or two predefined lists?

Comment: probably use isin() in your withColumn method:  `f.when(df['Portfolio'].isin(Portfolios), df['Portfolios']).otherwise('ALL')` http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin

Comment: @jxc, they were originally columns from different dataframes. So I used `portfolio_DomainItemLookup = filterDomainItemLookUp.select("Portfolio").rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()` to make them lists. They need to be auto generated as values will vary by dataframe.  Both  `portfolio_DomainItemLookup`  and `portfolio_dataset_standardFalse` are lists.

Comment: The way I understand, it'll always generate the same value "ALL", because `matchedPortfolio` is static when the `withColumn` is triggered. Do you want something to iterate that changes the value of `matchedPortfolio` for each row?

Comment: @jxc, using isin() makes a lot more sense! Tried it, and got this error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name &#34;Portfolios&#34; among (SourceSystemName, Portfolio, PortfolioRule);`

Comment: I had a typo in my code, just change `df['Portfolios']` to `df['Portfolio']`

Comment: @samkart, `matchedPortfolios` will generate 2 scenarios. One where no matches are found, thus column `PortfolioRule` should be fill with `"ALL"`. Second scenario will be that it prints the actual matches `[ABC Portfolio, XYZ Portfolio, 123 Portfolio]`, thus I will need to compare `Portfolio` column in order to fill the correct value for `PortfolioRule`, in my example, ABC Portfolio then. For my initial question, I was troubleshotting how to apply to "ALL" condition. @jxc

Comment: Yeah, in that case `isin()` does this best.

Comment: @jxc, good catch! Full code `new = dataset_standardFalse.withColumn('PortfolioRule',f.when(dataset_standardFalse['Portfolio'].isin(Portfolios), dataset_standardFalse['Portfolio']).otherwise('ALL'))
display(new)` fills my columns where Portfolio has no match, thank you! And if I understand it correctly, if there is a match, it will be a straight copy from `Portfolio`column?

Comment: @jessgtrz, yes. :)

Comment: @jxc, thank you!! This is a  **much** simpler process then what I was going for.

Comment: @jxc, qq, is there a way to only print distinct values on a list? So far I've only seen methods for columns. I'm using `filterDomainItemLookUp.select("Portfolio").rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()`. I can post it as a new question after my 90min restriction

Comment: @jxc, works great, thanks again! Is there a general name for this format/ method? [ xx for xx in ] in pySpark?

Comment: I think you can try: [ p.Portfolio for p in filterDomainItemLookUp.select('Portfolio').distinct().collect() ]

Comment: @jessgtrz, it's Python's syntax, search `list comprehension`

Comment: I have a follow-up question, dropping the link, thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823544/pyspark-mapping-multiple-columns @jxc

Answer (score 0):

This fills columns where Portfolio has no match. And  if there is a match, it will be a straight copy from the Portfolio column

```
new = dataset_standardFalse.withColumn('PortfolioRule',f.when(dataset_standardFalse['Portfolio'].isin(Portfolios), dataset_standardFalse['Portfolio']).otherwise('ALL')) 
display(new)
```

Comment: **answer provided by@ jxc**

Comment: @jxc, so here we're not using mappings. Would you say in this case, the matching using `isin` is more efficient? Would the straight copy be the `Portfolio` in **THAT** row (if matched to the list) or would it be **A** Portfolio that's matched in the list?

Comment: not sure if you are referring to *mappings* in another different question. from my knowledge, `mappings` which takes O(1) in searching a key should be more efficient than using `isin` which is O(N) where N is number of item in the list.